# Windows 8 console why there are C: D: and X:

Tags: windows-8

My laptop stops working BSOD with code 0xc0002e3
It seems It can be a SAM problem so I'm trying some repairements booting with system recovery options from HD and selecting the console.
But I can see three diferent disks: 
C: labeled "system reserved" is 350MB
d: no label, has 380G free it's the big one
x:  label "boot" it's some MB.

But indeed there is only two partitions which  are corresponding to c: and d: so what is x:?  a virtual disk?

regards

Answer (score 1):

When booting into system recovery, the X: drive is the temporary drive used by the restore environment.  It has to be able to differentiate between the normal boot drive C: and the temporary boot drive X: .

I've found a lot of forums and help sites that reference this fact, but haven't seen an authoritative link from Microsoft stating it yet.  If I find one, I'll update this Answer.